# LESS is multiplying the output fro mixins

Tags: less

I have a mixin like this one:

```
#font {
  .set-size(@size: 14px, @spacing: 1.5) {
  font-size: @size;
  line-height: @size * @spacing;
}
```

And I call it from another stylesheet, like this one:

```
h1 {
  #font > .set-size(24px);
}
```

And then the compiler outputs:

```
h1{font-size:24px;line-height:36px;font-size:24px;line-height:36px;font-size:24px;line-height:36px;}
```

As you can see it repeats the output several times. Anyone knows why this occurs? I've tried with less.app and lessc from the command line with exactly the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an error trying to compile your bundle because it was missing a curly bracket.

I was able to successfully compile after that fix and it only output the values once. My code was as such:

```
#font {
    .set-size(@size: 14px, @spacing: 1.5) {
        font-size: @size;
        line-height: @size * @spacing;
    }
}

h1 {
  #font > .set-size(24px);
}
```

which output this:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 36px;
}
```

Comment: It was because I loaded the mixins file multiple times